# Is there a unique identifier for and Android and iOS available in React Native which does not change even after resetting or upgrading OS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, uniqueidentifier

I want to know if there is a unique ID for an Android and iOS Device, available in React Native. Also, the ID shouldn't change over app installs and OS install and upgrades. However, if it isn't, which Native Module should I use to get a unique ID. I actually need a unique ID to register my device at the server and send data to that device only. I don't really know if this is possible. As I searched, I found TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() for Android but could not found something for iOS. I did find identifierForVendor and identifierForAdvertising but they do change after resetting or upgrading OS

Comment: Even if it was possible to do this it would be a pain to maintain especially since the individual platform APIs may change or deprecate features over time. Might be easier to associate the device with a user account but I don't know your use case

Comment: use device token from react native firebase

Comment: You can store your own identifier in the keychain on iOS to survive app uninstall/re-install.  iOS upgrades don't affect device data.  There is no unique identifier for an iOS device that will survive the device being erased; this is by design on Apple's part.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data from the server to the device, you are looking for a push notification token.
This token can change over time, but it's easy to set up a listener to detect those changes and store a new token for that same device in the server part. In general, you are embracing token changes instead of trying to get a unique device identifier.

Here are popular libs:

- https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage
- https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification